# Unable to capture content of the scorm present inside the iframe using html2canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html2canvas

I am trying to capture the screenshot of the SCORM present inside the iframe but it is capturing content of the iframe, I am using [html2canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) for that. All the files of SCORM are present on same server.
This is first slide/page of my scorm.
[image] 
**1)** Firstly I have passed `$('iframe')` and `var iframe = document.querySelector("iframe").contentWindow.document.body;`
to `html2canvas`  but it is not working well.
**Output of this is following Img**
[image]

**2)** Then I passed `e.target.parentNode` to `html2canvas` so it capturing current element's parent.
 **Output this is following :**
[image]

Here is my code :

```
html2canvas($('iframe'), {
    logging: true,
    onrendered: function(canvas){
        before_imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
        // console.log(before_imgData);
    }
});
```

But I want screenshot of all the screen how can I achieve that, any help would be appreciated.